# Jhipster microservice with no registry

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I am trying to create a gateway+microservice setup (using jhipster 7.8.1) something similar to [this sample](https://github.com/jhipster/jdl-samples/blob/main/reactive-ms.jdl) but without eureka service discovery.

After generation, the applications boots fine but the UI (in my case Angular) is unable to reach the microservice (i.e unable to perform CRUD operation - I see 404 in the gateway). I did some initial digging and found the following in application.yml in gateway app

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - JWTRelay
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                pattern: "'/services/'+serviceId.toLowerCase()+'/**'"
          filters:
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "'/services/' + serviceId.toLowerCase() + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
                replacement: "'/${remaining}'"
```

which seems to be doing the routing, especially

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled:true
```

seems to be doing the magic of mapping the apps registered with the discovery service to be available for gateway proxy'ing ([reference](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#the-discoveryclient-route-definition-locator))

I looked into the [template](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/v7.8.1/generators/server/templates/src/main/resources/config/application.yml.ejs) in the jhipster's code base and did not find any other implementation for the no discovery service option.

For the no discovery service option I was expecting to see (with my limited knowledge of gateway) some explicit route mapping in the gateway to my microservices. Am i missing something or do I have to tweak something in the gateway to make it work without the discovery service.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Note: I was able to run my setup as expected with eureka discovery (jhipster registry)

Comment: You are expected to manually create your static routes for your services (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#route-metadata-configuration), the generator won't help here. It could do it in the case you generated your gateway and services within one JDL (see https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/applications#more-than-one-application) but that's a specific case, this is probably why it's not implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did create the applications using the sample JDL but the static routes were not created and that's why I went to the application.yml template in gateway to confirm that there is a static route option, but there wasn't. I will modify the gateway and make it work. Once again thank you!